# time.Time undefined

Tags: go

Trying to use a slice of type time.Time but it won't recognize time.Time as a type. Getting error *time.Time undefined (type int has no field or method Time)* I have imported time at the top in my imports and declared it as

```
var alarmTime []time.Time
```

but with no luck.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You probably have a variable named time somewhere. If it's not obvious, try to show us a bigger part of your program (if possible the minimal code demonstrating the problem).

Comment: Thanks for that! Just takes a second pair of eyes sometimes! :)

Comment: even I had the problem, don't know how I missed that. Thanks @dystroy

Answer (score 14):

You obviously have a variable named `"time"`, of type `int`, somewhere in your code.

Find it and remove it.

Answer (score 4):

add `import "time"`at the top of your file (after the `package ...` statement)

Comment: what is the complete compiler message?

Comment: and, do you have some function, constant or variable called `time` in the root scope?

Comment: time.Time undefined (type int has no field or method Time) Thats the compiler message. I've not used var as name for anything elsewhere.

Comment: it appears that you have an `int` called `time` right around the line-column of the error.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me, what I was doing wrong is that instead of putting `var test time.Time` I was putting `var test time.time` with lower case. Have a nice day!